# Toggle classes and aria attributes for panels, only one panel open at any time

Tags: javascript

I am scrapping the use of JavaScript libraries like jQuery for vanilla javascript. It would be good for any suggestions of improvement I could make for the following bit of code:

- I have a collection of panels
- Each panel contains a button and a content div

I require the ability to toggle on/off for each panel, but only one panel can be open or active at any one time.

- I'm adding classes and removing classes
- I'm adding ARIA properties and removing ARIA properties

My JavaScript works just fine, however, I am positive big improvements could be made and very interested for best approaches.

**Example JavaScript:**

```
function panel() {


    // Get elements
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('Panel');
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('Panel-button');
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName('Panel-content');


    var i;


    // Init
    for (i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
        button[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        content[i].setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    }


    // Reset
    var panelReset = function() {

        for (i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {

            button[i].classList.remove('Panel-button--selected');
            button[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);

            content[i].classList.add('JS-hidden');
            content[i].setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);

        }

    };


    // Click
    var panelClick = function() {

        if (this.classList.contains('Panel-button--selected')) {

            this.classList.remove('Panel-button--selected');
            this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);

            this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('JS-hidden');
            this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);

        } else {

            panelReset();

            this.classList.add('Panel-button--selected');
            this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);

            this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('JS-hidden');
            this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);

        }

    };

    for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i].onclick = panelClick;
    }

}


// Dom ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  panel();
});
```

**Example of some of the HTML:**

```
<div class="Panel">
  <button class="Panel-button" aria-controls="one">
    <span class="Panel-title">Button 1</span>
  </button>
  <div class="Panel-content JS-hidden" id="one">Content 1</div>
</div>

<div class="Panel">
  <button class="Panel-button" aria-controls="two">
    <span class="Panel-title">Button 2</span>
  </button>
  <div class="Panel-content JS-hidden" id="two">Content 2</div>
</div>

<div class="Panel">
  <button class="Panel-button" aria-controls="three">
    <span class="Panel-title">Button 3</span>
  </button>
  <div class="Panel-content JS-hidden" id="three">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this "example" code or actual code (example code is off-topic of code review)? How concerned are you with browser compatibility? Certain things like `classlsit.remove` are only supported on relatively newer browsers. The fact that you're using ARIA stuff implies that you want to support as many devices as possible and if that is the case, the truth is, you really should stick with jQuery.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. ARIA is for accessibility purposes. IE9 upwards.

Comment: Accessibility and compatibility go hand in hand. People with a seeing disability for example are probably more likely to skip a browser update. I'll write some notes when I get home.

Comment: I'm a little confused. A lot of the accessibility tags are supported in IE8 and above? I would be using javascript or jquery simply to toggle these attributes. Im not really following with what you are suggesting. Forgive my ignorance if I am missing the point? A user would not have to perform a browser update...

Comment: Well i'm only looking to cater for IE9+. It's a simple website so will most likely stick with jQuery. Thanks.